# Strange class initialization in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, numpy

In the python library [pytides](https://github.com/sam-cox/pytides), I came across a strange method to **initialize** a class (the [Tide](https://github.com/sam-cox/pytides/blob/master/pytides/tide.py) class and its [initialization](https://github.com/sam-cox/pytides/wiki/How-to-use-the-NOAA's-published-Harmonic-Constituents-in-Python-with-Pytides) ).
I reproduced below a simplified version of the code :

```
import numpy as np

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Foobar(object):
    dtype = np.dtype([('fooObj', object),
                      ('A', float),
                      ('B', float)])

    def __init__(self,model):
        '''model: an ndarray of type Foobar.dtype '''
        self.model = model


# initialize a Foobar object
myFoos = [Foo(4,3),Foo(4,9),Foo(0,2)]
A = [2,3,4]
B = [8,9,0]
model = np.zeros(len(myFoos), dtype = Foobar.dtype)
model['fooObj'] = myFoos     #what is that?!?
model['A'] = A
model['B'] = B
myFoobar = Foobar(model=model)
```

As I understand, the dtype variable in Foobar is a global variable, but I don't understand what's the point to have it. Is it just here to provide a convenient way to initialize Foobar? Moreover the Foobar class needs an array of Foobar.dtype at construction, is not a sort of cyclic call (which should crash)?

Comment: The `dtype` variable in `Foobar` is _not_ a global variable, it's a class attribute, which is shared by all instances of the `Foobar` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foobar.dtype` is a class attribute.

That is a variable which is attached to the definition of the class not a single instance of the class. If you're familiar with other popular object-oriented languages, this concept is very similar to a static variables in Java and C#.

Python docs which explains in more detail https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

---

Considering class Foobar in the example you've provided:

`Foobar` is a class

`myFoobar` is an instance of `Foobar`

let's pretend that there's another instance too: `yourFoobar`

then `myFoobar` and `yourFoobar` (and any other instances) may need to be able to have access to some data (in this case a definition of a `numpy` datatype) which is the same for all instances of `Foobar`. Thus there's an argument that it should be associated to the class rather than each individual instance. (However there are also arguments that class attributes / static variables do more harm than good: [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil))

i.e. avoiding a way of writing it where you allocate each instance of Foobar its own instance of the same numpy dtype definition, such as...

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self,model):
        '''model: an ndarray of type self.dtype '''
        self.model = model
        self.dtype = np.dtype([('fooObj', object),
                      ('A', float),
                      ('B', float)])
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I think I was confused by the name of the variable (dtype). The Python doc make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much that is strange about this initialization, `dtype` holds the types `Foobar` requires for the numpy array it receives durings its initialization (`model`). It's a class attribute, not a global one, so it is shared by all instances of the `Foobar` class.

The way `model` is initialized might seem odd, but it is just initializing `model` based on the name that specifies the field, this might be best demonstrated by printing out `model` in between the steps:

```
model['fooObj'] = myFoos
print(model)
array([(<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f125ed93828>, 0.0, 0.0),
       (<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f125ed93940>, 0.0, 0.0),
       (<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f125ed93240>, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('fooObj', 'O'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

adds the values for the `'fooObj'` object type. While:

```
model['A'] = A
model['B'] = B
```

adds the values for the `float` types `'A'` and `'B'` respectively.